# Glitter foil material in Three.JS

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to create a glitter-like material in Three.JS but I did not get the proper settings yet.

I tried to bring up roughness map like that:

[image]

and work with a white col-map but the effect just isn't there.

This is my material so far:

```
var material0 = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
                map: colMap,
                roughnessMap: rMap,
                roughness: 1,
                envMap: eMap,
                envMapIntensity: 20,
                normalMap: nMap
            });
```

Has somebody an advice?

Thanks!